# OpenCV + Realsense : Visual Studio Link 2019 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, linker, realsense

I can't integrate OpenCV with the Intel [Realsense Viewer source code.](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/tools/realsense-viewer)

Notes:
I'm currently on a Windows 10.

I'm using visual studio 2017. msvc 14.12

The opencv version is 3.4.1 (windows pack) that's the version that is pre built for you.

I built and installed the [intel realsense sdk from github](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense). This was successful. I also built and successfully install the [OpenCV examples](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/opencv) using [openCV I downloaded](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.4.1/opencv-3.4.1-vc14_vc15.exe/download) .

The problem comes when I try and link [OpenCV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.4.1/opencv-3.4.1-vc14_vc15.exe/download) to the [realsense viewer project](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/tools/realsense-viewer)

The steps I followed to try and link openCV to the Intel Realsense Viewer:

1. open the intel realsense sdk solution in visual studio (that's the .sln called librealsense2)
2. go to the realsense-vewier project inside the 'solution explorer' panel inside visual studio
3. right click on the project 'realsense-viewer' and then select properties
4. make sure the 2 drop down boxes above have 'x64' and 'all configurations'
5. Go to the C/C++ -> General option (from the left white box) and then go to 'Additional Include Directories'
6. Add in the directory %OpenCVDownloadRoot%/build/include and %OpenCVDownloadRoot%/build/include/opencv (this is the configuration of the example OpenCV projects

Now at this point, some functions from openCV weren't being linked properly inside the 'realsense-viewer' project (which is weird because the work in the OpenCV projects in the SDK, even though the properties are the same. The errors were as follows:
[image]

So then I followed some extra steps to see if I can get this to work.

7. Inside the properties dialog box (the one we were just in) instead of selecting C/C++, select 'Linker'
8. in the 'Additional Libraries Directories' selection, add in %OpenCVDownloadRoot%/build/x64/vc15/lib
9. inside the 'Linker' properties, search for Input (Linker -> Input)
10. add in 'opencv_world341d.lib' inside the 'Additional Dependencies' selection.

Now we get a completely different error:
[image]

Now the realsense libraries aren't being recognised. No other properties were modified except for the above. I can confirm that step 10 causes all of these errors. Even if I reverse the actions of step 10 after performing all the steps, the above error still remains -> this must be a visual studio bug.

Any help or hints on how I can get OpenCV 3.4.1 + realsense-viewer (from the SDK) working inside visual studio 2017?

EDIT: I have already read:
[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

But I have properly linked glfw and all of the other stuff that needs to be linked in order for the error message to go away. I believe the problem may be a bug that intel has, or a bug that vs has which requires a workaround

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found after taking a nice walk in the park( assuming you are using windows 10, visual studio 2017 for the project):

go into your local librealsense project folder

go to [C:\Users\yourName\to\your\local\realsense\folder\librealsense\tools\CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/tools/realsense-viewer/CMakeLists.txt)

Add this to the end of the file:

> find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
>
> list(APPEND DEPENDENCIES realsense2 ${OpenCV_LIBS})

so that the entire file is this:

> ## minimum required cmake version: 3.1.0 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
>
> project(RealsenseTools)
>
> ## Save the command line compile commands in the build output set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)
>
> ## View the makefile commands during build
>
> ## set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
>
> ## This parameter is meant for disabling graphical examples when building for
>
> ## save-to-disk targets. option(BUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES "Build graphical examples." ON)
>
> include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag) CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11"
>   COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11) CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x"
>   COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X) if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
>       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
>       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x") endif()
>
> if(BUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES)
>       find_package(OpenGL)
>       if(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)
>           message(FATAL_ERROR "\n\n OpenGL package is missing!\n\n")
>       endif()
>
> ```
> set(DEPENDENCIES realsense2 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
>
> if(WIN32)
>     list(APPEND DEPENDENCIES glfw3)
> else()
>     # Find glfw header
>     find_path(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES GLFW/glfw3.h
>         PATHS /usr/X11R6/include
>               /usr/include/X11
>               /opt/graphics/OpenGL/include
>               /opt/graphics/OpenGL/contrib/libglfw
>               /usr/local/include
>               /usr/include/GL
>               /usr/include
>     )
>     # Find glfw library
>     find_library(GLFW_LIBRARIES NAMES glfw glfw3
>             PATHS /usr/lib64
>                   /usr/lib
>                   /usr/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}
>                   /usr/local/lib64
>                   /usr/local/lib
>                   /usr/local/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}
>                   /usr/X11R6/lib
>     )
>     if(APPLE)
>         find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)
>         find_library(IOKIT_LIBRARY IOKit)
>         find_library(COREVIDEO_LIBRARY CoreVideo)
>         LIST(APPEND DEPENDENCIES ${COCOA_LIBRARY} ${IOKIT_LIBRARY} ${COREVIDEO_LIBRARY})
>     endif()
>     list(APPEND DEPENDENCIES m ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${LIBUSB1_LIBRARIES})
>     include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})
> endif() else()
> set(DEPENDENCIES realsense2)
> if(NOT WIN32)
>     list(APPEND DEPENDENCIES m ${LIBUSB1_LIBRARIES})
> endif() endif()
> ```
>
> ## allow this project to access opencv find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
>
> find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
>   set(DEPENDENCIES realsense2 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
>
> add_subdirectory(terminal) add_subdirectory(fw-logger)
>   add_subdirectory(enumerate-devices) add_subdirectory(realsense-viewer)
>   add_subdirectory(data-collect) add_subdirectory(depth-quality)
>   add_subdirectory(rosbag-inspector)

Then rebuild the project using cmake gui